# Prevent Line Breaks Within Input Type Text

Tags: text, input, line, break

For some reason the line keeps breaking when typing in an input type=text element. I thought this  behavior is default to textarea elements not input type=text elements. How can I prevent this?[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's how a textarea works. Try using the [input tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp) with type text:

```
<input type="text" name="sampletext" value="try this, this text will not have line breaks">
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9nqorarw/

Answer (score 0):

You should use a textare instead of an input field. It is easier then.

`<textarea type="text" name="sampletext" value="try this, this text will not have line breaks"></textarea>`